# How to loop through an array and add to it in JSON

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, json

I have an array containing several variables from my sql database.

```
{"gold":"0","silver":"0","bronze":"0","gdp":"12959563902","population":"3205000","country_name":"Albania"},              {"gold":"1","silver":"0","bronze":"0","gdp":"188681000000","population":"35468000","country_name":"Algeria"}
```

I have an additional variable called $score that uses information from the database to calculate this score. I want to know how I can loop through and add the correct score to each country in the array.

My Original Code:

```
$row = $res->fetchRow();
$resGold = $row['gold'];
$resSilver = $row['silver'];
$resBronze = $row['bronze'];
$resGdp = $row['gdp'];
$resPopulation = $row['population'];
$resCountry = $row['country_name'];
$gold_score = ($resGold * $gold_value);
$silver_score = ($resSilver * $silver_value);
$bronze_score = ($resBronze * $bronze_value);
if($population == true){
$score = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resPopulation);
}
else if($gdp == true){
$score = (($gold_score + $silver_score + $bronze_score)/$resGdp);
}
$result = $res->fetchAll();
$result[] = array('score' => $score);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: You need to decode your json string using `json_decode` function.

Comment: @Rikesh Why do I need to decode it when I want to put it together?

Comment: You need to decode it to perform any operation on it's value. And encode it again once you have done.

Comment: Because you first have to turn your json string into an array before you can use foreach on it.

Comment: How score is related to gold, silver & bronze ? I can't see any score field in the json.

Comment: @Sumoanand That is because I need to add it to json. I already used a calculation to work out the score for each country. I need to add this score into the json with some sort of loop.

Comment: @Rikesh I am only using json_encode at the end

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be something like this:

```
$json_data = '{"gold":"0","silver":"0","bronze":"0","gdp":"12959563902","population":"3205000","country_name":"Albania"},
        {"gold":"1","silver":"0","bronze":"0","gdp":"188681000000","population":"35468000","country_name":"Algeria"}';

$countries_info_new = array();
$countries_info = json_decode($json_data);

foreach($countries_info as $country_info){
   $country_info['score'] = Get_country_score($country_info['country_name']);
   $countries_info_new[]=$country_info;
}

$new_json_data = json_encode($countries_info_new);
```

Comment: I get this: *Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file on line 63* which is where $countries_info = json_decode($json_data);

Comment: Then it is already decoded, comment out that line & use it directly. Also, use print_r or var_dump to understand how data is flowing.